# JQuery checkbox value on check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

A multiple number of checkboxes are created on a html page with PHP in the following format:

```
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="att[]">
```

The number of these checkboxes varies depending on other variables, for this reason I have given each one the class "check".

On check of any checkbox, I want its value to be "YES". When a checkbox is not checked, I want it's value to be "No".

I have tried using the following jQuery to do this but have been unsuccessful.

```
if (($this).next('.check').is(':checked')) {
        ($this).next('.check').val('Yes');
    } else {
        ($this).next('.check').val('No');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".check").change(function(){
    //alert("checked");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).val("yes");
        //alert($(this).val());
    } else {
        $(this).val("no");;
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tppg/)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how checkboxes work. If it's checked, its value will be passed to the server.

Just set the value originally to `Yes`:

```
<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="att[]" value="Yes">
```

Comment: I need it to have a value if it's not checked too. It is to be sent to a database, I need a value for both on submission of the form.

Comment: @user2620746 - So do that server-side.

Comment: As you can see in the name attribute I'm putting the value into an array. This array contains other input types too. When posting to an array and a checkbox is unticked, it is skipped by php and not given a position in the array. Therefore server side can't help me and I need to use JS to define a value before the form is submitted